# Does a let statement breaking a join chain affects the performance of Kusto on querying?

Tags: performance, azure-data-explorer, kql

Let's say I have a KQL as below. It queries the result of the joining on the tables A, B and C.

```
A
| join kind=leftouter B on Column1
| join kind=leftouter C on Column2
```

I wonder if changing the join chain into the expression below impacts the performance of my query.

```
let joinAnB = A | join kind=leftouter B on Column1;
joinAnB | join kind=leftouter C on Column2
```

Does a let statement break the optimizer of Kusto query?

Answer (score 2):

> Does a let statement breaking a join chain affects the performance of Kusto on querying?

**`let`** statements are just used for solving complexity of query and for easy understandability and readability and it Kusto/KQL queries do not change the optimization or performance based on no of let statements have been used.
AFAIK, there is no negative impact of using let statements.

Below example takes y as a separate value/table and you can also use x and y as different entities too.

```
let x= datatable(col1:dynamic,col2:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"hello":"world"}),dynamic({"foo":"bar"}),
    dynamic({"world":"hello"}),dynamic({"bar":"foo"}),
    dynamic({"foo":"bar"}),dynamic({"hello":"world"})
];
let y= x
| project col1;
y
```

In your example, if you use first way you want use only

```
A| join kind=leftouter B on Column1
```

this part then you need to type everything else you can simply use a variable by using let. So it is also used for maintainability.